# JavaScript function to bind events specified in object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm creating a function that gets in input a JavaScript object with this format:

```
var input = {
    'selector1' : {
        'event1'    : function(element,value){
            // ...
        },
        'event2'    : function(element,value){
            // ...
        },
        ...
        'eventN'    : function(element,value){
            // ...
        }
    },
    'selector2' : {
        'event1'    : function(element,value){
            // ...
        },
        'event2'    : function(element,value){
            // ...
        },
        ...
        'eventN'    : function(element,value){
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

My function bind the events this way:

```
function event_binder(events_fns){
    for(sel in events_fns){
        for(ev in events_fns[sel]){
            $(sel).on(ev,function(){
                console.log(sel+'+'+ev);
                var th = $(this);
                var func_to_call = events_fns[sel][ev];
                func_to_call(th,th.html());
            });
        }
    }
}
```

but when I run it, it shows that every event's been bound to the last event.

I created a jsFiddle for better explain my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/Polmonite/6rRgr/

As the `console.log` suggest, it seems that the event binding always use the last
function in the object.
If I'm interpreting right, it would seems that the evaluation of the `.on`
function only happens at the end, so it use the last values of `sel` and `ev`
variables (a scoping problem), but I don't quite understand how to fix it.

**EDIT:** I need to specify one thing: I want to create a working version of the `event_binder` function, not a working version of the jsfiddle, which is just an example.

Comment: @Anton: My objective is to create a working version of the function 'event_binder' specified in the question. Maybe it wasn't clear, sorry about that. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is scope - there is only one `sel` and `ev` variable in the whole function, which is overwritten each time. To create a new scope (with its own variables), you have to wrap them in their own function. Luckily, jQuery provides an iterating function that you can pass a function to, so that you don't have this issue: `$.each`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/6rRgr/3/.

```
$.each(events_fns, function(sel, funcs) {
    $.each(funcs, function(ev, func) {
        $(sel).on(ev,function(){
            console.log(sel+'+'+ev);
            var th = $(this);
            func(th,th.html());
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for the explanation and the code example! ;)